# Running MadGraph on Ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to run MadGraph on an Ubuntu virtual machine. The documentation for MadGraph states that I just need python 2.7 and the unzipped MadGraph to be able to run it.

Nevertheless, I can't MadGraph to run. Any help?

The problem rests in that several modules aren't being built because "bits" are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to install the missing bits with something like `sudo apt install libbits-dev`. I could be more specific if you said what bits are reported missing.